# How to recursively populate sub-categories?

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I've a table named `categories`.

The table structure is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

There are 3 types of items in the table:

1. **Main Category** (whose `parent_id` is -1)
2. **Second Level Category** (whose `parent_id` is any of the **Main categories**)
3. **Third level category** (whose `parent_id` is any of the **Second Level Categories**)

Here's some sample data:

---

-- Records of categories

---

```
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('1', 'A', '-1');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('2', 'B', '-1');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('3', 'C', '-1');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('4', 'a', '1');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('5', 'b', '2');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('6', 'c', '3');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('7', 'aa', '4');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('8', 'bb', '5');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('9', 'cc', '6');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('10', 'ccc', '6');
```

I want to get an output structure like below:

```
Main Category      Second Level Category        Third Level Category
A                           a                           aa
B                           b                           bb
C                           c                           cc
C                           c                           ccc
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how are categories decided ?

Comment: sorry didn't get your question. @NullSoulException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give it a try:

```
SELECT 
t1.title AS 'Main Category',
t2.title AS 'Second Level Category',
t3.title AS 'Third Level Category'
FROM categories AS t1
INNER JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.ID
INNER JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.ID;
```

You will get output structure like below:

```
Main Category      Second Level Category        Third Level Category
A                           a                           aa
B                           b                           bb
C                           c                           cc
C                           c                           ccc
```

[**Reference**](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)